# pause executing function on purpose

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple `.click()` function with some functions in it:

```
$mario.on('click', this, function() {

    var width_mario  = $window.width()/2;
    $contentw.animate({left: '100%', marginLeft: -width_mario, marginTop: 0}, 600);
    $fixed.css({'background-color': '#510000', 'left': '25%'});
    createMario();
    trigger(); // fire trigger not until createMario() is finished with animation
});
```

inside the function of `createMario()` are loads of jQuery `.animate()`ions. What I intend to do is, to fire trigger not until the animations of `createMario()`are finished. Something like the return function you can do if an animation is finished BUT inside the click function.

Thanks

edit: and not with `setTimeout()` because the animations have a random speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass it as a callback, something like this:

```
function createMario(calback_fn) {
    ...
    animate({...}, {duration: 12345, complete: callback_fn});
    ...
}
```

Make sure you add it to the longest `animate` call.
Note that may need to slightly change the animate syntax, see http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for different argument options).

Then do:

```
...
$fixed.css({'background-color': ... as before... });
createMario(trigger);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't *literally* do that. What you need to do instead is pass a reference to the `trigger` function *into* `createMario` and have it call that function when the animations are finished. Assuming the animations are via jQuery, they have a callback they call when they're done.

Comment: the problem with that is, I need `createMario` at another point where I don't want to trigger `trigger()`. I had it before!

Comment: @supersize: In that situation, just pass `null` or `undefined` (the default if you don't pass anything) or `jQuery.noop` into `createMario` and handle it. E.g. (within `createMario`) `if (callback) { callback(); }`

Comment: I'm not that good into jquery or js as that I know exactly what to do. Is an answer from you possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `element.promise.done(function() { trigger(); });` if you're animating 1 element in the `createMario` function, or you can attach it to the longest animated element also (the one that takes the longest to finish), and it will call the `trigger()` function after that element has finished animating.

Here's a jsFiddle I put together that exemplifies this:  http://jsfiddle.net/WPHmY/2/